# How to <use> the <svg> element correctly for loading external sources?

Tags: html, css, svg

I've followed many guides to adding external SVGs to a page... like this one : http://wearejh.com/design/inline-svg-use-element/

The code is like this:

```
<svg>
  <use xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Skull_and_crossbones.svg"></use>
</svg>
```

It just does not load, example here: http://jsbin.com/cipacitovo/edit?html,output

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have a look http://jsfiddle.net/zSRW5/ This might be helpful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per the [SVG specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/struct.html#UseElement)

> Unlike ‘image’, the ‘use’ element cannot reference entire files.

You need to add a [fragment identifier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) to the URL to indicate which item within the image you are trying to display.

If the file you're referencing does not have elements with id values then you'll need to edit that file and add ids to the elements you wish to reference.

Answer (score 1):

Since IE is dead, every modern browser supports Web Components.

You can create your own `<load-svg>` Web Component to load external SVG files, without the need for `symbol` and `use`,
**and inline them into the HTML document**

The use of shadowDOM is optional, so no styling leaks in or out, and (notorious in SVG) no more issues with duplicate ID values.

**All code required:**

Suggestion: Put this code in a `<script>` tag in the `<head>`

```js
customElements.define("load-svg", class extends HTMLElement {
  // declare default connectedCallback as async so await can be used
  async connectedCallback(
    // call connectedCallback with parameter to *replace* an existing SVG 
    src = this.getAttribute("src"),
    // attach a shadowRoot if none exists (|| prevents displaying error when moving Nodes)
    shadowRoot = this.shadowRoot || this.attachShadow({mode:"open"})
  ) {
      // load SVG file from src="" async, parse to text, add to shadowRoot.innerHTML
    shadowRoot.innerHTML = await (await fetch(src)).text()

    // append optional <tag [shadowRoot]> Elements from inside <load-svg> after parsed <svg>
    shadowRoot.append(...this.querySelectorAll("[shadowRoot]"))

    // if "replaceWith" attribute 
    // then replace <load-svg> with loaded content <load-svg>
    // childNodes instead of children to include #textNodes also
    this.hasAttribute("replaceWith") && this.replaceWith(...shadowRoot.childNodes)
  }
})
```

```css
path { fill: red }
load-svg,svg { display:inline-block; width:150px }
```

```html
<load-svg src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/heart.svg"></load-svg>
<load-svg src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/heart.svg">
 <style shadowRoot>
   path { fill: green }
 </style>
</load-svg>
<load-svg replaceWith src="https://svg-cdn.github.io/heart.svg"> </load-svg>
```

Two optional **attributes**:

`shadowRoot` **moves** the DOM element ***to*** shadowDOM

`replaceWith` **replaces** the `<load-svg>` DOM element with the loaded files **content** (thus your `<svg>`)

Note: this Web Component is not restricted to `*.svg` files, you can load any file

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use svg in img tag.Because you are not generating anything instead you are loading.

[Check the example](http://jsbin.com/bemamatuyu/1/edit?html,css,output)

Comment: using SVG as an image won't allow you to access the elements inside it, so would'nt work for me.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot to add `xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"` in `<svg>`.

This is how it should be:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <use xlink:href="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/53/Skull_and_crossbones.svg"></use>
</svg>
```